# Submitting form with golang http library

Tags: forms, go

Oke, I'm currently trying to login in to my school website, with my own Crawler. Altough they have some protection against login. First I do a Get request to the Website so I get the token from the hidden Input field. That token I use in my next Post request to login to the url! But for some reason the http response is that I cannot resubmit the form. But with doing the same in Postman rest client (chrome plugin) I can login!

When I try to submit a form to this url:

```
postLoginUrl = "?username=%s&password=%s&submit=inloggen&_eventId=submit&credentialsType=ldap&lt=%s"
loginUrl     = "https://login.hro.nl/v1/login"
```

where %s are filled in credentials

```
req, err := client.Post(loginUrl, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", strings.NewReader(uri))
```

I'm getting as response that the Form cannot be resubmitted.

But when I try it with Postman rest client, I'm allowed to login.

code for Csrf token:

```
func getCSRFtoken() (key string) {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(loginUrl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    types := doc.Find("input")
    for node := range types.Nodes {
        singlething := types.Eq(node)

        hidden_input, _ := singlething.Attr("type")

        if hidden_input == "hidden" {
            key, _ := singlething.Attr("value")
            return key
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

> `goquery.NewDocument` is a http.Get()

My question now is, how does the URL get's formatted from the library

Comment: Please show selfcontained, runnable code. I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oke, I'm currently trying to login in to my school website, with my Own Crawler. Altough they have some protection against login. First I Do a Get request to the Website so i get the token from the hidden Input field. That token I use in my next Post Request to login to the url! But for some reason the http response is that I cannot resubmit the form. But with doing the same in Postman rest client (chrome plugin) I can login!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would be better off using:

`(c *Client)PostForm(url string, data url.Values) (resp *Response, err error)`

from  net/http like http://play.golang.org/p/8D6XI6arkz

With the params in url.Values (instead of concatenating the strings, like you are doing now.)

Comment: This is the response

`<form method="get" action="action="login" onsubmit="javascript:window.location='login';return false;">
 <p class="important">
  There was a system error while handling your request, please try again or contact your local helpdek. 
  <br />
  
  <br/>
 </p>
 <div class="controls">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="login" value="try again" class="button" />
 </div>
</form>`

Comment: The form is using a get request now, which is not possible, i've modified the code to the code u wrote in play.golang